# Excel read - modify multiple column value while reading - Java, logic

Tags: java, logic

I am a peculiar problem where I have to work on data given in a spreadsheet (xls,csv). I would be using that data in my java program.

The spreadsheet data is generated elsewhere and I have no control on it. In it, there are a few columns which have a system-peculiar formatting and I should have an option to choose **"programmatically"** on how to convert each of this to the format I need.

Simple approach in my project would have been to

```
 a) read the spreadsheet and apply transformations in place while reading.   
 b) read each row as a java object and iterate over this list and do the modifications
 c) use some in-memory DB like H2 and apply some **user-defined functions** (dont know how) either while reading into the memory or transforming it later.
```

At this point of time, I really do not have all 3 options figured out in detail. So please excuse the vagueness.

Is there any other option of doing it? And more importantly, because i can have thousands of records where more than 5 columns may need to be transformed, **what is the quickest approach?**

Answer (score 0):

First you can check if the the file is excel or spreadsheet.
If its excel you can use Apache poi,its really useful to parse the excel file.In this case you can apply transformation while reading.

Spreadsheet is comma separated so you can use the split function and parse it.In this case you cannot apply transformation while reading, but collect in an Array and do the same.

Performance depends upon how you optimize the code.You can use Java 8 Streams to stream line and make effective use of code.